# 'Invalid syntax' error when importing torch (Linux)

Tags: linux, pytorch, conda, python-import, torch

I'm trying to install torch under miniconda and simple `import torch` gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/vol/tcm17/username/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 779, in <module>
    from .serialization import save, load
  File "/vol/tcm17/username/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 18, in <module>
    from typing_extensions import TypeAlias
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/typing_extensions.py", line 880
    if stripped_args
```

Interestingly, if I repeat `import torch` again the error message changes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/vol/tcm17/username/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 249, in <module>
    for name in dir(_C):
NameError: name '_C' is not defined
```

I'm not using notebooks, python version is 3.8.16, pytorch version is 1.13.1. Miniconda is installed in a local folder (it's a university server so I can only do it like this due to disk space restrictions), the server runs on Ubuntu.
What could possibly be the problem?

The only recommendation I found for similar problems is to install Cython but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Downgraded to python 3.6 and this somehow solved the problem.